# How to plot graph online

Tags: graphing-functions

Need help plotting $0\leq t\leq 2\pi$, $z(t)=e^{(1+i)t}$ and $z(t)=e^{(-1+i)t}.$
How can I plot them online or any software that I should use to get the graph of such curves?
I am familiar with Wolfram but not able to get this.

Comment: @Moo I suspect that he wants the parametric curve lying in the complex plane, rather than the graphs of the real valued functions of the real and imaginary parts of $z(t)$.

Answer (score 3):

Specify that you want a parametric plot and explicitly break it up into the real and imaginary parts like so:

```
parametric plot (Re(exp((-1+i)*t)), Im(exp((-1+i)*t)), t=0..2pi)
```

[That input](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+%28Re%28exp%28%28-1%2Bi%29*t%29%29,+Im%28exp%28%28-1%2Bi%29*t%29%29,+t%3D0..2pi%29) yields the following:

[image]